# Cache IMemoryCache read-thru in .Net Core MVC

Tags: .net, caching, asp.net-core

Have implemented cache read-thru as below in a .net core web application. Want to validate if this is OK or I could run into issues with this.

**Startup.cs, ConfigureServices**

```
services.AddMemoryCache();
```

**Helper/Extension Method**

```
public static class MemoryCacheExtensions
{
    internal static async Task<T> ReadThrough<T>(this IMemoryCache cache, string key, Func<Task<T>> func, int minutes = 1440) where T : new()
    {
        var items = new T();
        if (cache.TryGetValue(key, out items)) return items;
        items = await func();
        if (items != null) cache.Set(key, items, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes));
        return items;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
internal readonly IMemoryCache _cache;
public async Task<IActionResult> Active()
{
    var children = new List<Child>();
    var key = "children-active";
    return Json(await _cache.ReadThrough<List<Child>>(key, () => { return _context.Child.AsNoTracking().Where(c => c.IsActive == true).ToListAsync(); }));
}
```

Being used to cache EF query results currently. Is this OK, or are there any reflection (performance) related, thread related or other issues that could come up because of this?